# grepping data Apache access.log

Tags: linux, apache, bash

I want to have a real-time copy of /var/log/apache2/access.log so i can grep, do hostname resolution, etc.

What's the best way to do this?

I am curious to see what kind of traffic is passing by

Comment: Where do you want to have this real-time copy? How do you want to access it? If you just want it in a terminal, use `tail -f`

Answer (score 1):

You could:

1. configure apache to send logs via syslog, than configure syslog to obtain separated logs files (with specific owner). Take a look at: [O'Reilly : Sending Apache httpd Logs to Syslog](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/sysadmin/2006/10/12/httpd-syslog.html)
2. use tail -f, but you have to ensure that following commands are unbuffered in order to read events immediately

   `tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log | grep --line-buffered "something"` or

   `tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log | sed -une "/something/p"`
3. Make the `tail -f | grep` using perl or python (perl is a good choice for grepping in log files).

(This sample are copied from man perlfaq5:

```
for (;;) {
    for ($curpos = tell(GWFILE); <GWFILE>; $curpos = tell(GWFILE)) {
               # search for some stuff and put it into files
    }
    # sleep for a while
         seek(GWFILE, $curpos, 0);  # seek to where we had been
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
#Customize as appropriate:
tail -f  /var/log/apache2/access.log | cut -f 0 -d ' ' &
tail -f  /var/log/apache2/access.log | grep foo &
```